# AI - Removing ghost lines from path tracing before merging to a compound path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, image-trace

**Here's the task:** I import an image, trace it black and white, and then try to convert the result into a compound path in order to use it easily later on.

**Here's the problem:** When I combine to a compound path, nothing shows up - either it appears as completely white or completely black. All the vectors forming the object are still there, but the result is blank.

**Here's why:** When I trace the object, it creates duplicate lines. Each line that appears in the result is actually two lines on top each other - even when *ignoring white*. In the result, the first set of lines wrap the actual object fill areas. The second set of lines either wraps all the white sections (if not *ignoring white*), or wraps nothing, and acts as just lines. When converted to a compound path, fill-content is ignored. Since vector shapes in compound paths invert when intersecting, everything fills together, making everything appear one solid black rectangle (or nothing at all if there's another line-vector wrapping the border).

**Here's the question:** How can this be avoided when tracing? Or, perhaps, how can I remove all the empty lines before combining to a compound path?

Comment: Usually you should not answer your own question in the question. Just make a self-answer, that is wellcome here to keep questions and answeres divided ...

Comment: Well, ya - I would if I had enough "reputation". I couldn't separate it within the first 8 hours.

Comment: I'm sure you will soon have the reputation to do it ;-) The other thing in my eye is that Scott already gave the same answer. Who was first?

Comment: I separated it. And I actually answered it first. I kinda figured it out as I was asking the question, but I still put it up since I figured it could help others with the same problem - plus in case I could get a better answer. p.s. What do you mean the _same_ answer?

Comment: Great, thanks! Well, for me the answer of @scott looks well ... (but I'm not an expert on this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I just figured it out - so for those who might wonder, here's an answer.

- Trace the object *without* ignoring white.
- Use the magic wand tool to select all the white areas.
- Then delete them.
- *Then* combine to a compound path.

Because all the white areas are gone, they won't become black when combined (since varying fill-style is ignored when combined to a compound path). For more details, read the *why* in the question.

Although there might be other ways, this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Image Trace. Ignoring white or not doesn't really matter other than if you want white or not. The steps below work with or without white.

- Expand the trace and Pathfinder > Merge. This removes the superfluous objects.
- Sometimes it's also helpful to draw a no-fill, no-stroke rectangle and choose Select > Same > Fill & Stroke then hit delete.

The merge step will automatically create compound shapes. There's no need for you to do it manually.

Comment: I'd perhaps accept your answer if I could get it to work, but I've tried it over and over again, and "pathfinder > merge" is not doing anything. When you say that, do you mean "effects > pathfinder > merge"? Keep in mind, I am using cs6.

Comment: No, just the merge button on the Pathfinder Panel. Works every time for me.

Comment: Oh the panel - I just tried it but it still doesn't seem to merge it to a compound path. Note I want to merge everything from the expansion to a _single_ compound path.

Comment: works here. Not sure why you don't get similar results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great way to manipulate lines in Illustrator and may help answer his question. 
1. select all
2. select sketch in image trace (sketch works the best)
3. open window/image trace palette
4. select various options by watching more in depth in this video I found: https://www.video2brain.com/en/lessons/converting-art-to-vector-with-image-trace
5. This allowed me to increase the threshold to 180 and picked up all my lines. You can reduce noise to about 10%. 
6. Lastly, you can use the eraser tool in outline mode and not see any of those crazy lines you saw before.
7. I struggled all night and found this video and this enabled me to have my object fully outlined perfectly and edit it.

Hope this is of help!

Answer (score 0):

What I found was the lines came in as different colors so I just selected the color i didn't want > SELECT > SAME > STROKE COLOR > DELETE. That got rid of one layer of lines.